# Sublime Text 3: Is it possible to have project specific session without remembering last session?

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to have separated session instances of Sublime Text 3 for different projects, but currently I have following behavior:

Run `subl --project A.sublime-project`
Close Sublime Text 3 via `x` button

Run `subl --project B.sublime-project`

It opens project `A` and then project `B`.

But I want only `B` project and it's session to open. I have to manually close `A`

I tried to change following settings:

```
"hot_exit": false,
"remember_open_files": false,
```

But then Sublime Text 3 always starts new session (forgets opened windows).

Is it possible to open my project from command line so, it does not open last session but opens only project session (and it's windows)?

For example in Eclipse I could do `eclipse -data someDir1` close eclipse and then `eclipse -data someDir2` and it opens only `someDir2` associated session and does not care about `someDir1`